# Custom control with both ContentPresenter and ItemsPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have built a custom control that has two regions for content, looking like this:

```
+-------------+
| L |         |
| o |  Main   |
| g | Content |
| o |         |
+---+---------+
| Interaction |
+-------------+
```

I did this by inheriting from `Control` and adding two dependency properties `MainContent` and `UserInteractions`. When using the control, I do something like this:

```
<controls:ScreenControl>
    <controls:ScreenControl.MainContent>
        <TextBlock>Some content goes here</TextBlock>
    </controls:ScreenControl.MainContent>
    <controls:ScreenControl.UserInteractions>
        <Button>Do something</Button>
    </controls:ScreenControl.UserInteractions>
</controls:InstallerScreenControl>
```

The corresponding control template looks, slightly simplified, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ScreenControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ScreenControl}">
                <DockPanel Width="530">
                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <!-- Some static content -->
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainContent, RelativeSource={...}}"
                                          DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={...}}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="LightGray" Height="50">
                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding UserInteractions, RelativeSource={...}}" 
                                              DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={...}}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, I want to allow several elements in the `UserInteractions` region. However, `ContentPresenter` only allows a single element. From reading, it seems I need to use `ItemsPresenter`, but that this only works if I inherit from `ItemsControl`?

I tried setting the type of the `UserInteractions` dependency property to `ObservableCollection<UIElement>` (most articles I found just set it to `object`, so that was what I had), and this works in-so-far that there is no compilation error with several children, but on rendering it only displays `(Collection)`, not the actual buttons.

What am I missing?

Comment: Panel is your choice here.

Comment: @pushpraj: How do you mean?

Comment: You should use an ItemsControl and bind its ItemsSource property to your UserInteractions. The default item container type of ItemsControl is already ContentPresenter, so everything should work out of the box.

Comment: could you share your custom control? may I try to com up with something. @Clemens has just posted a nice solution however as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that `UserInteractions` is a collection of UI elements, this should work out of the box:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserInteractions, RelativeSource={...}}"/>
```

If the UserInteraction objects are pure data object, you would also have to define the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserInteractions, RelativeSource={...}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I'm getting "The member 'Content' is not recognized or is not accessible". Some other property meant? I tried `ItemsSource`, which works in that it shows the first item, but not any more of them.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error. Yes, I meant ItemsSource of course. Provided that `UserInteractions` is a collection of objects, it should show them all.

Comment: It did, but my `StackPanel` was put to surround the `ItemsControl`, rather than in a `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`. So they stacked wrong. Thanks for the help!